# How to override the "No web page was found for the web address" message?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, tomcat

The **"No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost/blabla"** message is generated as a response to the request with an illegal path. I need to return a custom message instead of this one. Any idea how to do it?

The server is embedded Tomcat with

```
spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update `httpd.conf` and point to new page maintenance.html ( call it anything) and place it somewhere where it can be accessed.

```
// comment anything existing add line below
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
```